# How do I get MiKtek to find Windows web app Overleaf file when I type pdflatex -shell-escape FFstats_v12 at the command line?

Tags: pdftex, miktex, overleaf

Sorry to ask this simple question, but I'm stumped.  Here are the steps I've taken:
In order to process large .tex files in Overleaf.  I added to the document preamble
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize.
Next as a stackexchange answer instructed, I added the pdflatex command, pdflatex -shell-escape FFstats_v12 at the command line.
I installed MiKTek but MiKTek can't find the Overleaf file. Where is the location of the edit file FFstats_v12 on my PC?

Below are my lines I input at the command line and the responses:

> C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64>
> pdflatex -shell-escape FFstats_v12
> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.4) (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)
> \write18 enabled.
> entering extended mode
> ! I can't find file `FFstats_v12'.
> <*> FFstats_v12

Note: I did find but could not access an Overleaf.lnk file stored here on the PC:
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\New folder>cd C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Desktop\Overleaf.lnk
The system cannot find the path specified.
But maybe this will be useful,create short cut to .lnk file: [https://fileinfo.com/extension/lnk#:~:text=An%20LNK%20file%20is%20a%20Windows%20shortcut%2C%20which,by%20right-clicking%20that%20object%20and%20selecting%20Create%20shortcut](https://fileinfo.com/extension/lnk#:%7E:text=An%20LNK%20file%20is%20a%20Windows%20shortcut%2C%20which,by%20right-clicking%20that%20object%20and%20selecting%20Create%20shortcut).

Comment: your overleaf project is on their server, miktex can not see that, use the download link on overleaf to get copies on your local machine

Comment: Thank you David, very much.  Spent hours on this last night.  But also learned things, this and I had to install MikTek.

Comment: shall we delete this question?